# Re-abstracting overriden method

Tags: c#, methods, virtual, abstract, class-hierarchy

Let's look at the following class structure:

```
abstract class Base {

    public abstract void DoSth();
}

class Derived1 : Base {

    public override void DoSth() {

    }
}
```

These are base classes for some hierarchy. Now, let's assume, that we want to provide another class deriving from `Derived1` (let's call it `Derived2`), which should not use the default implementation of `DoSth` provided by `Default1`. For example, Derived1 covers 98% of cases, but in the remaining 2%, this solution is not acceptable or dangerous.

The best solution is to notify someone who derives from `Derived2`, that he should implement DoSth during compilation. How to do that?

Answer (score 6):

C# allows "re-abstracting" the method. One may write:

```
abstract class Derived2 : Derived1 {

    public abstract override void DoSth();
}
```

From now on, `DoSth` becames abstract again and compiler will refuse to compile class derived from `Derived2` if it does not provide its own implementation of `DoSth`.

Comment: The answer was posted at **the same** time as the question?!!

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM That's perfectly ok. In fact, when you ask a question there's even a specific option to "answer your own question". Try it - click "Ask a question" and look near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, Sorry I didn't know that. (and I'm on SO for more than 3 years).

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM, whilst answering your own questions is fine, posting duplicate questions isn't :) Voted to close...

Comment: @DavidArno It's not really duplicate since the two questions pretty much answer each others.

Comment: Interesting that C# allows that.  Is there any way to convince it to allow one to both override and shadow a member without having to define an "intermediate" derived type?  For example, if a type declares `public abstract int foo{get;}`, can a derived type implement that member and declare an `int foo{get;put;}`, or is the only way to make that work to have the base type use `public int foo {get {return getFoo();} protected abstract int getFoo();`?

Answer (score -2):

Best way i can think of the top of my head is:

```
class Derived1 : Base
{

   public override void DoSth()
   {

   }
}

abstract class Derived2 : Derived1
{
   public virtual new void DoSth()
   {

   }

}
```

Comment: -1 There is a better way. And it already exists as an answer. Shadowing is almost never a good idea.

Comment: really???...hummmm ok i guess msdn saying its the default behavior when implementing your own in a derived class is wrong...."almost never" does not mean every time...

Comment: That does not solve the problem either. Someone, who derives from `Derived2` won't easily know, that he *must* override `DoSth`.